# Rviz error: undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData11detach_growEPii

Tags: ros, rviz, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I got the symbol lookup error while running: rosrun rviz rviz

[ INFO] [1347616386.332295872]: rviz revision number 1.8.14
[ INFO] [1347616386.332370571]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1347616386.427520048]: Loading general config from [/home/tienthanh/.rviz/config]
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization/rviz/bin/rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization/rviz/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData11detach_growEPii

Just happened after got update by Ubuntu Update Manager
System: Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, ROS Fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43841/rviz-error:-undefined-symbol:-_zn9qlistdata11detach_growepii/) by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. Actually, I got install a 3rd party package with libqtGui.so.4.6.2 in /usr/lib. Just remove it then everything is fine.

---

Originally posted by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) with karma: 231 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0